# How to specify a particular conda environment to run pytest code against?

Tags: python, pytest, conda

I have created some tests in `Tests.py` using `py.test` framework.

And I am using the following bash command to run in terminal:

`py.test --junitxml result_Tests.xml Tests.py`

But in this case `py.test` is picking the default python installation.

How do I specify a conda environment name to `py.test` so that it runs on that specific conda environment?

I could not find any specific `py.test` switches in their docs.

Comment: Is the env your wish to run in activated when you do this? Another option might be `conda run py.test --junitxml result_Tests.xml Tests.py`, though it unfortunately won't return output until the subprocess has exited.

Answer (score 11):

This is pretty obvious and probably not what you're looking for, but - assuming 'python' is the conda environment's -  using

```
python -m pytest
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

The proper manner to specify the conda environment in which a command must run is using the `conda run` command, passing the env name with the `-n` flag. In your case:

```
conda run -n <env_name> pytest tests.py --junitxml result_Tests.xml
```